# How to import nominal features in numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
Botnet_Training_data = np.genfromtxt("training_data.txt", delimiter = ",")
```

This is the code I use to import data from a text file however, when I print the data this is what I see:

```
print (Botnet_Training_data[0])

    [  0.00000000e+00   nan   nan   nan
   4.91000000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
```

I know that nan means not a number but I would like to know how to import nominal features, if it is possible

and side question does sklearn support nominal features?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'nominal'.  But as a default `genfromtxt` is importing values as floats.  If it can't convert the string to a float, it places `nan` in that slot.

Try `dtype=None`, and show us the `.shape`, and `.dtype` of the result.

A similar answer suggesting the `dtype=None`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27067667/901925
and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092934/901925

I ask about shape and dtype because it probably will produce a 1d structured array - which leads to other common `genfromtxt` questions.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Does it really matter?  It's on the long side for a comment.  If the OP adds details I intend to expand on my answer.  I don't like extended dialogs in comments.  Answers allow better formating.

Comment: It matters in the context of the site. _Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements._ You've done both as an answer.

Comment: This is an answer.  I'm guessing that the `nominal` features are strings, which he wants to import as such, not as floats. Using `genfromtxt(..., dtype=None)` will do that.  I've answered quite a few `genfromtxt` questions (about 90).

Comment: What's funny is that in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36092934/901925 I make a comment that answers the question, and no one bats an eye about format.  In other cases I've copied a comment to an answer.